# building imagick PHP extension on Mac OS X High Sierra

Tags: bash, imagemagick, automake, php-extension, macos-high-sierra

I'm having trouble installing the imagick extension to PHP. http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

I'm using the binary distribution of ImageMagick hosted here https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php for Mac OS X (no homebrew).

I've installed `pkg-config` as requested by the `phpize` configure script.

### The problem (I think)

The problem is `pkg-config --libs MagickWand` gives me the following result:
`-L$MAGICK_HOME/lib -lMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI`

I don't understand why `$MAGICK_HOME` is taken literally. I have exported the variable as instructed in the former link.

This leads to the following lines during configuration:

```
./configure: line 4479: cd: $MAGICK_HOME: No such file or directory
./configure: line 4526: cd: $MAGICK_HOME/include: No such file or directory
```

Configuration is successful, but of course building with `make` fails (MagickWand.h not found).

### What I tried

I went into all the ImageMagick `.pc` (pkg-config) files and manually hardcoded all entries of $MAGICK_HOME with the proper installation path.

Configuration went better, but building still failed at one point, once again because of a bad reference where `$MAGICK_HOME` was taken literally (and the path not found).

Therefore, I don't think tracking down all instances of `$MAGICK_HOME` is an optimal solution.

What am I doing wrong?

PD: I'm avoiding homebrew

Comment: Did you configure ImageMagick to be installed in a custom location, or default to `--prefix=/usr/local`?

Comment: I copied it to `/usr/local/bin`, so `$MAGICK_HOME=/usr/local/bin/ImageMagick`. The uncompressed software works right out the box. There are no configuration or installation scripts bundled.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone bumps into this problem...

### What worked

I compiled and installed ImageMagick from source (https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php). It would seem the precompiled version is not suitable for development.

On compiling and installing programs from source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-to-compile-and-install-programs-from-source

Comment: After installing, how do you add it to PHP as an extension?